# The "point at infinity" in Alexandroff compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactification

I am confused that from where the extra element $\omega$, "the point at infinity" come from in Alexandroff compactification.
For example, in the stereographic projection of $\Bbb R$ onto $S^1$, we take this $\omega$ as the set $\{\infty, -\infty\}$. But I think of this as an educated guess for the $\omega$ which works out to be correct.

But in the proof of this compactification, we assume from the start that $\omega$ exists. But I find this confusing that how can we know beforehand that such a point will exist for all the locally compact Hausdorff spaces? I feel that we need to prove it but I couldn't find this explicitly mentioned in any text that I searched.

My professor gave me the argument that we can take $\omega$ as some point from the space itself if needed and then compactify the complement of $\omega$ but I find many difficulties with this approach such as:
the original space $X$ may be finite in which case $X$ cannot be homeomorphic to $X\backslash\omega$
$X\backslash \omega$ may not be locally compact Hausdorff subspace of $X$.

I am sorry if I am being vague but feel free to suggest edits to make the question better.

Comment: the point $\omega$ does not need to be a point of $X$, or even related to the elements of $X$. You are actually gluing an extraneous point to your space through the topology you define in the compactification

Comment: @Exodd that is exactly my question that how can we be so sure that such extraneous point will always exist?

Comment: Your point $\omega$ could be anything not in $X$. For example, you could define $\omega = X$, since no set is an element of itself. What the actual point is matters very little once you define the topology on it.

Comment: if you talk about "existence" of a point, then you are thinking that you are working in some "global space" containing $X$. That's not how general topology work. You can always take a new point that has no connection to what you have. Then, in particular cases, and according to the topology you define, you can identify the new point as a special entity (for the compactification of $\mathbb R^n$ it is the "infinite" point, that is called infinite, because you can prove certain properties)

Comment: @Exodd I was not thinking about global space containing X but anyways, I think I understand your argument. Following your argument, in the example of $\Bbb R^n$, can we take $i=\sqrt{-1}$ instead of usual infinity?

Comment: Only if you don't relate $-1$ to anything in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: @Exodd okay. thanks

Comment: @user793679 that was quite clever. it really helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are given a set $X$ with some topology. We're working in a universe of sets, so there are always sets $A$ that are *not* an element of $X$ (there is no universal set, by Russell's paradox, or $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is a strictly larger set than $X$, etc. There are several argument depending on your axioms, e.g. if Regularity holds, then $A=X$ itself will work, as $X \notin X$ in that case). However we get it, we have some point (or set, as everything is a set) $\infty \notin X$.

We then proceed to define a topology on the larger set $X \cup \{\infty\}$ etc.

It's somewhat similar to working inside $\Bbb R$ and declaring the existence of some abstract number $i$ that satisfies $i^2=-1$ (and so cannot be a member of $\Bbb R$) and constructing the complex numbers from that. In that case we can also find another "model" for it, by using the product $\Bbb R^2$ and seeing $i$ as $(0,1)$ etc. In topology we can also often find a model for the Alexandroff compactification of $X$ inside some other space we already know (like $\Bbb S^2 \subseteq \Bbb R^3$ for $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb S^1$ for $\Bbb R$, or a "figure 8" in the plane for $(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ etc. We can then show that this concrete space is homeomorphic to the abstract construction $X \cup \{\infty\}$ we start with. But we don't *need* that model to define the Alexandroff compactification, it's a helpful intuition, sometimes.